# Laravel, first user is only user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am building a Laravel site for personal use and I would like to make the first user to register on the site be the only user. So with a fresh Laravel install with the ui installed, migration sorted and no users registered, I would like the register route to be reachable. But if there is a registered user, block the register route and only allow the login route to be reachable.

I could do something like this in the web.php

```php
Route:get('/register', function () {...})->auth();
```

But I would have to do that after I first create a user. I'd rather do it in a more controllable fashion.

**Edit**

---

I don't doubt that [@yves-kipondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6108283/yves-kipondo)'s answer is the more correct option if I were to create this for someone else.

The solution I went with is a simple one. In my register controller I just add a check in the constructor, if there already is a user return a 404.

```php
public function __construct() {
  if (!User::all()) {
    $this->middleware('guest');
  } else {
    abort(404);
  }
}
```

Comment: `web.php` is a `.php` file, you can add logic/PHP code in there. Check if there's a user, if not, register the route

Comment: @kerbh0lz I suggest using a middleware instead. The `web.php` file gets called on every request even if the request is for a completely different route and that would cause the query to be unnecessarily executed. I believe that using your strategy it won't be possible anymore to cache the routes file too.

Comment: @dan it would be possible to cache it but you would have to cache it after the user was created so that condition is met and it wouldn't be adding the route ... caching would remove the additional query every request ... but there are different ways to go about this

Comment: There are a lot of way. 1. After register user remove route `Auth::routes();` you cant register anymore. 2. Change the code of RegisterController in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php` change the function create like that: 

`protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if (User::find(1)->count() == 0)
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
       return null;
    }`

Comment: if this is only for your use i would just not have a registration system at all, and add the user myself or write a command to interactively create that user

Comment: @lagbox As this is for a personal project, I think that would be the best option, requiring the least amount of extensive "one off" solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Middleware which will be register on the `register` route

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RegisterOnce
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (User::count() !== 0) {
            // you can redirect wherever you want 
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

After that you can register the middleware in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` by adding this line after all registered routes middleware like this

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    \\ ... previous registered middleware

    'once' => App\Http\Middleware\RegisterOnce::class,
];
```

and you can customize the `register` route like this in the `routes/web.php` file
which wille replace the default set by `Auth::routes()`;

```
Route::get('register', [App\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])
    ->name('register')
    ->middleware('once');
```